# Is it possible to open a locally saved Flash file on the Ideapad A1?

Tags: adobe-flash, lenovo-ideapad-tablet-a1

Is it possible to open a Flash file (.swf) locally on [Lenovo A1 tablet](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/tablets/ideapad/tablet-series/a1)? (Something like open it through the Android browser?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Smart SWF Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andy.flash) app.

Answer (score -1):

Your browser should be able to open a swf directly if you have [flash installed](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).
If clicking on the file doesn't do it, then your file extensions for swf need to be set up, to associate swf with your preferred browser.

Comment: The tablet is using Android.